# Glasshfish jndi lookup failed

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, glassfish-5

I am new on stack, this is my first post, so sorry if I did something wrong.
I'm trying to connect my glassfish 5 server with my MySQL database in NetBeans 8.2, but every time time I try to deploy my web application, glassfish console gives me

`Exception while deploying the app [appname]: JNDI lookup failed for the resource: Name: [appnamePU], Lookup: [java:app/jdbc_blogdb], Type: [javax.sql.DataSource]`

I have tried to reconfigure JDBC connection pools at glassfish admin panel, but after restarting the server it always returns this exception. I'm pasting screenshots of glassfish admin panel with JDBC resources and glassfish-resources.xml file as well. Do you have any idea, why glassfish doesn't want to cooperate with my database?

[glassfish-resources.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzjTl.png)

[JDBC Connection Pools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyAVe.png)

[JDBC Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA0HE.png)

[Full error from netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhAQT.png)

[edit]

 I forgot to add, that this error is shown only when i try to run and deploy my web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your glassfish-resources.xml add:

```
<resources>
    <jdbc-resource 
        enabled="true" 
        jndi-name="jdbc/jdbc_blogdb" 
        object-type="user" 
        pool-name="connectionPool">
        <description/>
    </jdbc-resource>
    <jdbc-connection-pool

        ...

    </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

And be certain that you have your jdbc jar in place. In case you don't know if you have it. Put your mysql jdbc jar in glassfish-[VERSION]\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext

Usually glassfish creates a default domain as domain1 ... if you have changed that, use your domain where is "domain1"

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use this sub-context in the code for looking up-

```
java:comp/env/jdbc/jdbc_blogdb
```

Comment: so everything with glassfish setup was configured properly, i mean JDBC connection pools, resource and in glassfish.xml every name is as they should be right?

Comment: This doesn;t workNetBeans tells me

Resource [ java:comp/env/jdbc/jdbc_blogdb ] is not allowed to specify the scope [ java:comp/ ]. Acceptable scope for this resource is [ java:app/ ]